# Load event of an element with a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Suppose you have made a new directive in angularJS with attribute restriction, say `my-directive`.
Suppose to have the following HTML code:

```
<img src="..." my-directive />
```

Now, the *load* event of the `<img>` is triggered only when all the code of `my-directive` is executed and the DOM is completly loaded, or when all the information of the *natively* `<img>` tag are loaded (for example the src data, the style, ...)?

I want to know this information because I want understand what is the effect to intercept the load event inside the code of a directive.

Comment: How would the DOM load event even be aware of Angular?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum it doesn't have to, angular compiles the DOM as  a multi-stage process for just this reason. OP... you need to use a pre-link function in your directive instead of the normal link:... so you'll actually need to define both. read up here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch That was a rhetorical question so that OP can come to the conclusion themselves :) Sorry for being misleading, that was not my intention.

Comment: thanks for clarifying.  Consider though... is not the purpose of Stack Overflow to help questioners learn by providing answers first, and wisdom second?  Although in this case... I do see your point. With advanced Angular, it is fundamental to understand the relationship between the DOM and angular and the lifecycles of both.

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch Thanks! I didn't know of `post-link` and `pre-link`. If I use link, for example with the img tag, when the code is executed I can stay sure that the image data is loaded and ready for manipulations? so there isn't reason to intercept the load event?

Comment: I think we're coming full circle to @BenjaminGruenbaum comment.  What would be the purpose of intercepting the load event?  `ng-src` supports angular expressions, so you have a lot of ability with angular to compile that final outcome however you wish before it even starts loading.  It sounds like you may need to touch up your familiarity with angular a bit, especially how it's bootstrapped, what the compiler does, and how directives work at different stages of those processes.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've not completely studied angularJS. I'm knowing new sides of Angular while I'm coding an app for fun.
In the specific I have posted this question because I have to apply a JQuery code only when the element is completly load and from the moment that this JQuery code is called inside the directive I didn't know if was correct to use a code like `$(elem).load(foo)` or it was useless.

Comment: angular has jquery built in. check angular docs for whatever feature it is you're trying to use first to make sure you're not clobbering angular with your jquery code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my comment mentions, you'll likely want to use a pre-compile link funciton, but you will also be aided by using `ng-src` instead of the native `src` attribute, which allows angular to insert itself into the process.  Then you can do your interception prior to compilation like so:

```
module.directive('interceptImg',function(){

    //other functions on your directive like template and controller

    compile:{
        return: {
            pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller){
                //you can listen/bind your events here by accessing iElement
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Checkout the [docs for $compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)